# What does the phrase "absurdly" mean in this contextual setting?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

Marriage is an absurdly painful communion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The writer is being creative, making an unusual comment about marriage, a very widespread institution.
[Merriam-Webster "absurd"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/absurd)
1 ridiculously unreasonable, unsound, or incongruous: *an absurd argument*
extremely silly or ridiculous: *absurd humor*

The word "absurdly" is the adverb form, and it applies to the word "painful".
The best fit from the meanings in the definition is "incongruous" = "inconsistent within itself" (linked at the previous definition).

So, I think the author means that the fact that marriage is so painful is inconsistent with it being so widespread.

However, the exact meaning may depend on the surrounding text or speech, which I haven't been able to find.